# Creating a responsive menu system for a site with a lot of content

Tags: routes, theming

I am currently creating a website which has a lot of content - text. For this I need a serious menu structure with 5-10 menu items per menu and at least 15 menu-blocks per main menu item.

Further it has to be accessible via mobile.

Till now I have used panels and added menus inside the panels. But mobile isn't to happy about that and the list-names in the menus overlap the content.

How would you go about solving this issue? I trust you experts here! :-)

Answer (score 4):

for creating responsive menu you have lots of projects

below are some

https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus

https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_navigation

https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_dropdown_menus

https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu

try any one will help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking into a couple of third-party javascript and/or jquery plugins you can integrate with Drupal to provide a more unified menu experience for both desktop and mobile users.

**Big Slide Menu - Mobile Push Menu**

The first, more tested option is to utilize the Big Slide Menu plugin, which creates a mobile push-menu, which can account for several layers of depth, without demanding too much screen real-estate.

https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu

This option may be difficult to integrate the with Drupal Menu system, but it would certainly give you a robust solution, which can accomodate you needs for a large more complex menu system.

**Snap.js -  Mobile Shelf Menu**

The second, but perhaps more complicated option is to integrate Snap.js, which provides a mobile-shelf "type" menu.

https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/

To my knowledge it's not a module for Drupal, but that being said you don't have to do much to combine the plugin with drupal.

First, you have to be able to edit the page.tpl.php, which is where you want to add the snap-content selector to page container.

Second, you have to add the Snap content container, which will contain the responsive-ready menu system. I recommend adding this below the page container. You will either want to add a new region in this location ( so you can add blocks from admin/structure/blocks) or create a function to add the appropriate menu to the location. I definitely don't recommend hard-coding the menu in, but it may be a consideration in your case if the menu is static and you want to make the design process a little easier.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! However this is a bit to custom for my taste :-)