# Menu for mobile responsive

Tags: 7, routes

[image]

Is there any recommended module for responsive menu?

Example the picture above, click on it and a list of menu appear.

Easy to configure.

This content is for: many content

[Creating a responsive menu system for a site with a lot of content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149050/creating-a-responsive-menu-system-for-a-site-with-a-lot-of-content)

Mine is simple. Basically the menu wont have a link. (It is just a scroll down function to specific height when I click the menu.) Just that when come to mobile, I wan it act like responsive menu according to the picture above. It wont have any sub-menu as well.

Comment: Superfish also has mobile functionality, that one isn't mentioned in the duplicate

Comment: @Clive I edit my question. Any recommendation?

Comment: The duplicate has a list of modules you can use, regardless of the content size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option is the [Responsive Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus) module.

> Responsify your menus! Just give me a CSS/jQuery style selector of
>   your menu and I will make it mobile friendly (when the time is right).
>
> Technically you could set this to affect any element on the page...
>   e.g. collapse a sidebar or content area at a certain screen width.
>   (Using certain styles).

Comment: I edit my question. Is Responsive Menus module going to help me to solve my problems?

Comment: @peifa Install it, try it, then you'll know. Q+A isn't a substitue for you doing your own due diligence on a project